# Let $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(c)$. Then what is $E[\exp(i\langle z, S_{N}\rangle)]$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, independence, random-walk, poisson-distribution

Let $N \sim  \mathrm{Poisson}(c)$ with $c  > 0$.  Let $(S_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a random walk independent from $N$. In a proof I'm reading, it is claimed that

$$E\left[\exp(i\langle z, S_N\rangle)\right] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N=n) E\left[\exp(i\langle z, S_n \rangle)\right].$$

I can't see why this holds. I tried writing $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_{n} I_{\{N=n\}}$ and this gives a good intuition for why the formula should be true, but I can't justify why the formula holds.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write $$ \exp (i \langle z, S_N \rangle) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(i \langle z, S_n \rangle) I_{\{N=n\}}. $$

Now take expectations and use independence. (Be careful to justify taking limits out of the expectation operator.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can switch expectation and sum by dominated convergence, since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |\exp(i \langle z, S_n \rangle )I_{\{N=n}\} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty I_{\{N=n\}} = 1$ and $1$ is integrable? Is that correct?

Comment: Let me be more explicit. Define $g_k = \sum_{n=0}^k \exp(i \langle z, S_n \rangle) I_{\{N=n\}}$. We want to show that $\mathbb{E}[\lim_k g_k] = \lim_k \mathbb{E}[g_k]$. Thus, we want to find a dominating function for $|g_k|$. This dominating function is $1$, as my previous comment tried to explain. Doesn't that work?

Comment: @user745578 you're right, that does work, and is in fact a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for the verification! Much appreciated!